# Pi Zero, No Input

Tags: pi-zero

For the life of me, I can't get my Pi0 to work on any TVs other than the one in my living room. I gave this to a friend and they can't get it to work on their TV, either.

I'm just running RetroPie... same cords and power supply. It works great on the 55" Samsung, but not on any other TVs. I uncommented hotplug, safe, and set groups to different values. I also set the resolution to default in raspi-config.

This is a most disappointing thing, as I wanted to give this as a gift, but I can't even get it to turn on any of the other 4 TVs here in my house.

Comment: what does `/boot/config.txt` look like?

Comment: I'm assuming your using a good quality hdmi cable. Are you selecting the correct input on the TVs before turning on the Pi?

Comment: @CoderMike Thank you for the response. Yes. I have the type suggested by the community to be using and the TV inputs are set right.

This thing works... but I gave it to a friend and she couldn't get it to work on her TV. I can only get it to work on my big living room TV.

Comment: @CoderMike 
So here is what I did after work today: I formatted the SD card and started the RetroPie process all over again. Right now, it's working well on the 15" Insignia in my guest room. But the resolution is terrible. No matter what hdmi_mode I use... or what I uncomment. The resolution is not 1080... but even if I figure it out here, my friend won't be able to use it on her TV. Probably. :(

Comment: @JaromandaX After work, I did a fresh install on the SD card. I refuse to connect it to the big living room tv. haha. But the config file: I uncommented the safe=1 and hotplug=1 lines. I ended up uncommenting the group and mode lines and they are set to 1 and 16. 

I set the raspi-config resolution to default... and I don't know... I'm just getting exhausted with this. I'm about to go try a different TV. This guest rm TV has little red dots and poor resolution.

Comment: All `15" insignia`TV's I've found in google are 720p max resolution - you can't do 1080 on a 720p display!

Comment: Yes... I've tried all the CEA numbers up and down the list. Why is this so finicky from one TV to the next? What I really want is for my friend to be able to take it home and use it with her family. 

Thanks for the slapback to reality, though. Yes, you're right about the resolution. I've just been at this for hours. And I already worry about giving it back to my friend.

Also, I just plugged it into a little 15" Element and it says Unsupported Mode. Sure, and the initial startup screen blinks in every now and then, but mostly blue screen.

BTW: I have a Pi3 and it works great.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. This TV just keeps blanking out or flickering with red lights. I really don't care, as no Pi will be connected to this TV in the future. But I can't give this to my friend without knowing it will work. Why is this so hit or miss? It won't work at all in the office, it looks like crap in the guest room, and it did work in the living room. But I refuse to connect to that tv right now. My Pi3 works on all 3 TVs so it's gotta be a PiZero thing. I put one in an NES cartridge but I guess this won't work. Too unstable from TV to TV

Comment: I've only ever had one TV that had an issue - but it has issues with many devices - this TV for some reason does not like 1080p input (regardless of refresh rate), 1080i is fine, and all other modes are fine. Not much can be done about faulty televisions!

Comment: @jaromandax Yes, no keyboard. Thank you for your replay, again. I ended up just doing a whole refresh download of the retropie image. Reformatted the SD card and all. Didn't take long and it corrected whatever I may have done wrong here, concerning password logins.

Well, I couldn't get it to work on either small monitors, but it worked fine on a 40" Samsung we have downstairs. Works like gangbusters. Lousy resolution, though... But I'm afraid to mess with any settings. I just want this to work on most TVs. The only thing uncommented was the safe=1 line of HDMI.